# Monotonicity of sequence determined by a summation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

I'm studying for my calculus exam and I'm stuck with the next exercise, I have to find out the monotonicity of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ with the next general term:
 $$a_n=\sum \limits_{p=1}^n\frac{1}{n+p}$$

For it to be monotone, the next condition must be proved: $a_n\le a_{n+1}$(incremetal) or $a_n\ge a_{n+1}$(decremental), so:
 $$\sum \limits_{p=1}^n\frac{1}{n+p}\le\sum \limits_{p=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(n+1)+p}$$

$$or$$

$$\sum \limits_{p=1}^n\frac{1}{n+p}\ge\sum \limits_{p=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(n+1)+p}$$

I'm stuck here, I don't know how I can operate this in order to verify if the sequence is monotone.

Comment: I hope "monotony" is not to be taken literally. Perhaps you meant "monotonicity?"

Comment: @ChrisLeary Funny. The natural translation of the spanish word for monotonicty to english would be monotony, hence his mistake.

Comment: @GitGud Yep thats what happened, im not native english speaker hehe

Comment: Since the numbers $a_n$ are all positive, you can erase the absolute value signs, thereby making your life much more pleasant.  (Actually, I'm not sure why those absolute value signs were there in the first place.)

Comment: You can see the monotonicty by writting out $a_n$ for a couple of terms. You'll see a pattern in the expanded summation.

Comment: @Alejandro: I was wondering if it might have been a translation matter. It reminds me of my school Latin class when I translated "naves oneribus" literally as "ships of burden," totally missing the idiomatic "transports." Please accept my sincere apology if I offended.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(p+1) = q$,
$$a_{n+1} = \sum_{p=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{n+1+p} = \sum_{q=2}^{n+2} \frac{1}{n+q} \\ = \sum_{q=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+q} + \frac{1}{n + n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{n+1} = a_n + A$$

Now it remains to show that $A > 0$. From [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%282+n+%2B+1%29+%2B+1%2F%282+n+%2B+2%29+-+1%2F%28n+%2B+1%29+%3E+0), we get $A>0$ for $n \in \mathbb N$

Further more, we have 
$$\frac{1}{n + n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{n+1} > \frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{n+1} = 0$$

And since we have $a_{n+1} > a_n$, the sequence $\{ a_n\}$is monotonically increasing.